# simulate cURL in php - and download a file

Tags: php, api, curl, download, zip

i am simulating a curl by using the following php code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.seedr.cc/rest/folder/63570589/download");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username" . ":" . "password");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

for example $result variable supposed to return a zip file containing an IDM.exe file

but I am unable to download the file

print_r($result) returns

```
{"space_max":113279762432,"space_used":104253784608,"code":200,"timestamp":"2018-08-09 18:47:16","id":63570589,"name":"IDM 6.27 Build 2 Registered (32bit 64bit Patch) [CrackingPatching].zip","parent_id":5279897,"torrents":[],"folders":[],"files":[{"id":332764141,"name":"IDM 6.27 Build 2 Registered (32bit 64bit Patch) [CrackingPatching].zip","size":10873724,"hash":"b74952bfeac28266451b80ac95c674ba8e9b79f3","last_update":"2018-08-09 18:47:16","stream_audio":false,"stream_video":false}],"result":true}
```

how to download the result variable as zip file?
I am actually working with seedr.cc [api](https://www.seedr.cc/pulse/api-doc/)

TIA